# "Has Bluetooth Enabled" or "Is Bluetooth Enabled"

Tags: grammaticality

Having a debate at work...

Current headline reads "Product-X Has Bluetooth Enabled". Does that make sense? Or should it be "Product X Is Bluetooth Enabled"?

Comment: Both? More context may be required depending on intended meaning.  If the device has bluetooth capabilities, it 'is bluetooth enabled'.  If the device has the bluetooth turned on, it 'has bluetooth enabled'.  If the device previously had no bluetooth capabilities but a recent upgrade gave it such capabilities, 'is bluetooth enabled' is preferred, but I've seen 'has bluetooth enabled' in use.

Comment: I think this is really an [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) level question.

Answer (score 5):

As Doc says, it depends what you're trying to say, but if you mean the product has Bluetooth capability, I would add a hyphen thus: "Product X is Bluetooth-enabled".

Comment: To be clearer: “Product X is Bluetooth-enabled” (with hyphen) means that Product X has the ability to use Bluetooth; “Product X has Bluetooth enabled” (without hyphen) means that Product X has a Bluetooth ‘switch’, and that it is currently set to ON. On most smartphones, for example, you can turn Bluetooth on and off—these phones are always Bluetooth-enabled (since they have Bluetooth built in), but it is only when you actually turn on Bluetooth that the phone has Bluetooth enabled; otherwise, it is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

"Has X enabled" implies that X is a configuration item that is inherited from some standard source.

> My cell phone has Bluetooth enabled.
>
> Our new application has Windows themes enabled.

"Is X enabled", in contrast, implies that X is a feature that required a significant amount of creative work to implement.

> The new Wasmodo laptop is Bluetooth-enabled
>
> Our new security door system is 911-enabled.

Both usages are usually, but not always, technology related.